# Opencart Image Manager not showing large files

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module, opencart2.3

I am creating a theme for opencart but facing issue such as when I upload a small image in image manager it shows in the folder but when I upload a large image(4MB) then folder does not open.

I use Opencart 2.3, all image folders are chmod 777.

I do not what is the problem is causing this error.

Comment: Do you have a related error in your error log?

Comment: No there is nothing in error log about this. It's running perfectly on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

I think, You have get the following Allowed memory size error there.

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to
>   allocate 4000 bytes) in /home/public_html/system/library/image.php on
>   line 34

You will need to change Memory limit size in `php.ini` file for that.

Go to Your site source > admin folder > and Open `php.ini` file.

And then change `memory_limit = 64M;` to `memory_limit = 128M;` and then check it.